# Why does my Game Maker DLL give an access violation?

Tags: c++, dll, access-violation, dllexport, game-maker

I found a [tutorial](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=405812) about making your first C++ DLL, which I wanted to try by making a function that calculates the octave number of a certain frequency. I first tried the example function, multiplying two values, and that worked. Then I put my calculating function, which I first tested in a standard c++ project, in the DLL code. Now when I want to call the function in Game Maker, it gives me [this popup](http://gyazo.com/376d0005734a9756c470b1b929045939) and when I click the OK button the program hangs.
Does anyone have an idea what could cause this access violation?

Compiler information: I am using NetBeans IDE 7.3 in combination with Cygwin 4 (gcc).
Compiled and tested on Windows 7.

DLL code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

#define GMEXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)

double A440 = 440;

GMEXPORT double __cdecl SampleFunction(double a, double b) {
    return a * b;
}

GMEXPORT int __cdecl freqGetOctave(double f) {
  double a = 12*log2(f/(A440/16))+.505;
  int c = (int)(a+9)/12;
  return c;
}
```

Game Maker code:

```
//script: dll_init
globalvar _exmpl,_freq;
var dll_name;
dll_name = "c:\Users\<me>\Documents\NetBeansProjects\GMDLLtest\dist\Debug\Cygwin_4.x-Windows\libGMDLLtest.dll";
_exmpl = external_define(dll_name, "SampleFunction", dll_cdecl, ty_real, 2, ty_real, ty_real);
_freq  = external_define(dll_name, "freqGetOctave", dll_cdecl, ty_real, 1, ty_real);

//script: example
return external_call(_exmpl,argument0,argument1);

//script: freq_octave
return external_call(_freq,argument0);

//Watch Excpressions in Debug Screen:
example(3,3)        9
freq_octave(440)    [error popped up:]

//    [Access violation at address 00405B33 in module 'DLLtest.exe'.
//     Read of access 00000004.]
```

Comment: typical symptom of dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: One possible error is that your c++ function has an `int` return type, yet you're declaring it as `ty_real` in the `external_define` call.  (Looking at the documentation, it looks like you can only use `real`s or `string`s)

Comment: Time to run your debugger, and write a testcase. For the record: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22f1a4962bd01c34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding these exported functions:

> Plug-in functions must have a specific format. They can have between 0 and 16 arguments, each of which can either be a **real number (double in C**) or a null-terminated string. (For more than 4 arguments, only real arguments are supported at the moment.) **They must return either a real or a null-terminated string.**

Yours returns an integer, not a double. Game Maker will be trying to interpret that integer as a double, which does not go well.

- http://gamemaker.info/en/manual/414_00_dlls